# How much maximum "disk space" of an iOS device should be used while writing files from code?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, diskspace

We tried to check how much maximum memory is allowed to use while writing file with code, for that we used following procedure:

- We loaded video from itune to device to fill memory of device(it shows memory available 0.01 GB)
- The we wrote code to download video, before loading video we check how much memory is available(by code) and it shows 175MB.
- Now we load video of size 16.70 MB and it allows us to write that video in document directory
- But now when we see, our device in itunes it shows warning about extensive use of X MB of memory(i forgot the exact figure).

So my questions are:
How to put a check that my application stops using device memory extensively?
And when (on what amount of memory) we should put that check?

Comment: I recommend using the term **disk space** or **storage**, the term **memory** generally refers to the primary memory (RAM).

Comment: Thanks Anne, even you can edit it for good. Community'll appreciate you doing so.

Comment: Check this : http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/07/check-disk-space-capacity.html

Answer (score 0):

Dont put any check, the amount of memory you used is not a static value, it could vary depending on alot of factors.

What you have to do is to implement notification observers for memory warning, and depending on these callback, act and release some of your memory, dont try to calculate memory yourself, just depend on what iOS tells you, iOS will tell you when you are using a lot of memory

Comment: Oh No, you really didn't got me or my question need some editing. What i meant was in iTune device memory was full but i was able to write a video file in my document directory. There's no notification for this. Is there?

Comment: oh yes seems i didnt get it, let me read the question again :)